# Get data from CollectionView to the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

How to passs the data from collectionview to the next Viewcontroller?
I have a class

```
class Foods: Codable {
    var id : Int?
    var name : String?
    var image : String?
    var price : Int?
    var category : String?
    
    init(id: Int?, name: String?, image: String?, price: Int?, category: String?) {
       self.id = id
       self.name = name
       self.image = image
       self.price = price
       self.category = category
   }  
}
```

I need to know how to transfer the data from UICollectionView to the Detail Screen if I get all the data from JSON

Here's my code from ViewController

```
{
    class HomeScreen: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 
    var foodsList = [Foods]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "toDetail" {
                if let food = sender as? Foods {
                    let detailScreen = segue.destination as! DetailScreen
                    detailScreen.food = food
                }
            }
        }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foodsList.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductsCollectionViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell()}
    
    
    cell.configure(item: foodsList[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let food = foodsList[indexPath.row]
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: food)
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
    
    }
```

Comment: What's your code of the first `UIViewController` with the UICollectionView and how does it does to the DetailsScreen ?

Comment: I updated the code of ViewController

Comment: Your code seems correct. Is the code called? How did you create the segue ? From a Cell to `DetailScreen` or from `HomeScreen` to `DetailsScreen`?

Comment: From a cell to DetailScreen in storyboard

Comment: I just need that every cell in HomeScreen by clicking to eat will show me his details in DetailScreen

Comment: Remove the segue, redo it from HomeScreen to DetailsScreen.